# Unity Graphics White Screen Problem (Graphics Problem?)

Tags: unity-game-engine, ubuntu, graphics, driver, nvidia

My Unity Editor was showing a blank white screen when trying to start a project. Image here:

[image]

This is for the Karting Microgame. When it loads it only displays a blank screen. When clicking the play button there is sound but nothing showing on the screen. This issue also occurs for other Unity3D microgames. I suspect it is an error with the graphics setup or maybe a bug?

Technical details:

Dell G15 laptop

Ubuntu 20.04

Unity version 2020.3.21f1, installed via Unity Hub

NVIDIA Graphics Card (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 GPU)

NVDIA Driver Version 470 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nvidia-driver-470)

I also have an Intel integrated graphics card on my machine. Tried switching to integrated graphics via the sudo prime-select intel command but it didn't work. Also tried installing Dell G15 graphics drivers from the Dell website but it seems like they only have Windows graphics drivers. Currently the screen is still blank.

Relevant links:

- Unity forum discussion, have the exact same problem except for Ubuntu:
  https://forum.unity.com/threads/uni...n-problem-might-know-the-real-problem.545441/
- Dell graphics driver link, but seems to only have for Windows:
  https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/g-series-15-5510-laptop/drivers
- Tutorial on switching graphics cards. First tried updating my drivers via the ubuntu-drivers command from my existing 470 version to the recommended 510 version, but ran into an error saying my computer holds broken packages. Then tried switching to Intel integrated graphics card via the prime-select command but it caused my GUI to break (had to switch back to NVIDIA via the command line.)
  https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open windows in safe mode and try again also there might be other programs open that are causing the blank screen for example vpn could cause it

Answer (score 0):

I need to share this!

Try this:

1. In your project, delete the Library folder. I found that CurrentLayout-default.dwlt in particular must be deleted, so you can try that first if your project is big and want to avoid long rebuilding times.
2. In ~/.config/unity3d/Preferences/Editor-5.x, delete the Layouts folder
3. In ~/.config/unity3d, delete the Browser folder
4. In ~/.config/unity3d, delete the Editor folder (there is one sub-folder per editor version but the serial number cannot be trivially matched with a human-readable version, so maybe just delete the whole folder)
5. Restart the project

I found 1, 2 & 3 to work in my case, and only 1+2 or 2+3 not to work. At least it should work when installing a new editor / re-installing an editor version. I also did 4 at some point so it may be needed for editor versions already installed. I did 2 at the beginning so not sure if required.